# How to use Trust Wallet instead of Metamask on mobile browser?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps

Most DApps makes use of meta mask to sign transactions. I want my dApp to Make use of trust wallet when its opened on a mobile browser. How do I do this

Answer (score 1):

Try working through the connection documentation here: https://developer.trustwallet.com/wallet-connect